# Obtaining same resolution of pre and post UAV-Imagery In COSI-Corr?

Tags: coordinate-system

I am currently trying to perform a correlation between a pre UAV derived image of a  landslide with a post image to analyse displacement and direction.

The images were processed through SfM processing software Pix4D. I keep getting the following error:

[image]

Any advice?

I, unfortunately, am new to this software and have little time to grasp it.

Comment: To correlate the two images you need a pixel to pixel comparison. Look up how to resample one of the images to match the resolution of the other and try again